# Get Web Bot To Properly Crawl All Pages Of A Site

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl through all the pages of a website and pull out all instances of a certain tag/class.

It seems to be pulling information from the same page over and over again, but I'm not sure why, because theres a bell-curve-ish change in `len(urls) #The stack of URL's being scraped`, which makes me think I'm at least crawling through the links, but I might be pulling/printing the information out improperly.

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://weedmaps.com"
```

If I try using just the basic weedmaps.com URL, nothing prints, but if I start with a page that has the type of data I'm looking for...`url = "https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/shakeandbake"`, then it pulls the information out, but it keeps printing the same information out over and over again.

```
urls = [url] # Stack of urls to scrape
visited = [url] # Record of scraped urls
htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()

# While stack of urls is greater than 0, keep scraping for links
while len(urls) > 0:
    try:
        htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()

# Except for visited urls
    except:
        print urls[0]  

# Get and Print Information
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    urls.pop(0) 
    info = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"story-heading"})

    print info

# Number of URLs in stack
    print len(urls)

# Append Incomplete Tags    
    for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
        if url in tag['href'] and tag['href'] not in visited:
            urls.append(tag['href'])
            visited.append(tag['href'])
```

Comment: Can you share an actual link to the web site?

Comment: Just edited the question, and the URL.  Hope that helps put it in perspective a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the URLs you are putting into the queue (`urls`) are pointing to the same page, but to a different anchor, for example:

- https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/shakeandbake#videos
- https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/shakeandbake#weedmenu

In other words, `tag['href'] not in visited` condition does not filter different URLs pointing to the same page but to a different anchor.

From what I see, you are **reinventing a web-scraping framework**. But there is one already made that would save you time, make your web-scraping code organized and clean and would make it dramatically faster than your current solution - [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/).

You would need a [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider), configure the [`rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules) to follow links, example:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MachineSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'weedmaps'
    allowed_domains = ['weedmaps.com']
    start_urls = ['https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/shakeandbake']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/dispensaries/'), callback='parse_hours')
    ]

    def parse_hours(self, response):
        print response.url

        for hours in response.css('span[itemid="#store"] div.row.hours-row div.col-md-9'):
            print hours.xpath('text()').extract()
```

Instead of prints your callback should return or yield `Item` instances that you can later save to a file, or database or process in a different way in a pipeline.

Comment: @Teldridge11 well, that's a separate problem, but I would go through the Scrapy tutorial first to get understanding how Scrapy works and what the key components are. Thanks.